# Repairing or Recovering files from a Corrupted F2FS partition?

Tags: data-recovery, sd-card, f2fs

I have a f2fs partition with missing Superblock.  I made a disk image so I would not destroy the original partition trying to fix.

```
sd-repair# fsck.f2fs sd128.img 
Info: Segments per section = 1
Info: Sections per zone = 1
Info: sector size = 512
Info: total sectors = 249737216 (121942 MB)
    Can't find a valid F2FS superblock at 0x0
    Can't find a valid F2FS superblock at 0x1
```

Testdisk doesn't support F2FS.

I don't know if there is a way to rewrite the superblocks, I would like to recover my files or repair the filesystem.

Here is hex of what I believe is F2FS superblock, from a good partition

```
10 20 F5 F2 01 00 07 00 09 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 0C 00 00 00 09 00 
00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 
E1 0F 00 00 FF 0F 00 00 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 12 00 00 00 08 00 
00 00 E1 0F 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 0A 00 00 
00 2E 00 00 00 3E 00 00 03 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 31 8B 
E4 FB 13 D1 42 26 A5 07 EA 8A B6 70 A9 45
```

Here is the hex I found on bad partiton

```
10 20 F5 F2 01 00 07 00 09 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 0C 00 00 00 09 00 
00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 DC 01 00 00 00 00 
31 ED 00 00 22 EE 00 00 02 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 72 00 00 00 77 00 
00 00 31 ED 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 12 00 00 
00 F6 00 00 00 E4 01 00 03 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 16 CD 
C2 62 53 10 46 17 A5 B7 41 C6 8E AA 33 D5 73 00 64 00 2D 00 65 00 
78 00 74 00
```

The superblock seems ok, differences are because of 1 is 128 GB part and other is 8 GB part.  I don't know how to tell if the superblock is in the right location on bad partition.  There offset don't match, from what I can tell. But I'm not that good with hex editors so I don't know how to compare there offsets.

Update:
the offset for the superblock was wrong it was at 0x600 or 3 sector.  I removed the first 512 bytes from the disk image.  Now fsck.f2fs shows

```
sd-repair# fsck.f2fs -f trim_sd.img 
Info: Force to fix corruption
Info: Segments per section = 1
Info: Sections per zone = 1
Info: sector size = 512
Info: total sectors = 249704447 (121925 MB)
Info: MKFS version
  "Linux version 3.4.0-CM-g87d27dd (Adam@TheKeurig) (gcc version 4.9 20150123 (prerelease) 
(GCC) ) #6 SMP PREEMPT Sat Dec 17 21:28:57 CET 2016"

Info: FSCK version
  from "Linux version 4.9.0-3-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) 
(gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18) ) 
#1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2 (2017-06-12)"
     to "Linux version 4.9.0-3-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org)
(gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18) ) #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2 (2017-06-12)"

Info: superblock features = 0 : 
Info: superblock encrypt level = 0, salt = 00000000000000000000000000000000
Info: total FS sectors = 249704448 (121926 MB)
[f2fs_crc_valid: 477] CRC validation failed: cal_crc = 4076150800, blk_crc = 0 buff_size = 0x0
[f2fs_crc_valid: 477] CRC validation failed: cal_crc = 4076150800, blk_crc = 0 buff_size = 0x0
[f2fs_do_mount:1945] Can't find valid checkpoint
```

From what I can tell the partition has shifted, It might be on issue with partition table. All the data seems to be intact.  Is is using ms-dos partition table.

Comment: testdisk doesn't repair filesystems, it only recovers partitions (which contain filesystems).  The relevant tool would be the increasingly-misnamed `photorec` by the same author.  I think it will work for F2FS, though I'm not sure.

Comment: @sourcejedi it doesn't work.

Comment: Related: [F2FS lost data? won't mount and FSCK doesn't work](https://superuser.com/q/1225447/358758)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to recover, you could try `cat sd128.img | strings [options] | grep -C10 [pattern for recovery]`. This is pretty terrible though. But could give you a lead where you data might begin.

This page on  [Forensic Wiki](https://forensicswiki.org/wiki/Solid_State_Drive_(SSD)_Forensics) regarding SSDs might be useful reading, *though it mostly addresses the complexity of the **FTL** (flash transition layer), which maps the system-visible block device to the multitude of memory chips in the SSD, and automatically performs wear-leveling, bad-block tracking, background optimization etc.*